# Cons function not working

Tags: c, list, struct, infinite-loop, cons

I am currently trying to program a function that will cons a new element onto the top of the list, and push the rest of the list back... can anyone help me with this? My program does not work when I try to compile and run it. It goes on an infinite loop. 
Any help?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/* linked lists of strings */

typedef struct sll sll;
struct sll {
  char *s;
  sll *next;
};

/* By convention, the empty list is NULL. */

/* sll_cons : (char*, sll*) -> sll* */
/* build new list with given string at the head */
/* note: copy the given string to the list (deep copy) */
sll *sll_cons(char *s, sll *ss) {
  while (ss != NULL) {
      char* temp;
      temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(ss->s));
      temp = ss->s;
      ss->s = s;
      ss->next = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(ss->s));
      ss->next->s = temp;
      ss->next->next = NULL;
      ss = ss->next;
  }
  return ss;
}
```

Comment: well, `ss->s = s;` looks suspicious.

Comment: can I not do that? I thought that I was setting the pointer, "ss->s", equal to the pointer. "s"

Answer (score 0):

Three things I want to mention here.

**Point 1.** You did not check for the success of `malloc()`. You're dereferencing the returned pointer immediately. If `malloc()` fails, you'll be facing UB. [`ss->next->s`]

**Point 2.**  inside while loop, after allocating memory to `ss->next`, you're putting that to `ss` and then checking against not NULL, which will never usually be TRUE for `malloc()` success.

**Point 3.** `temp = ss->s;` no, that's not the way you perform a *deep copy*. You have to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy). Otherwise, there's no point allocating memory to `temp`.

Comment: so to avoid this, should I add an "if" clause within the "while" statement?

Comment: @LeehoLim I did not look at your code logic, but yes, you should always check the return value of `malloc()` for NOT NULL and then use the returned pointer furthermore.